# How to scroll down and click button for continuous web scraping the page in python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I want to scrape the full page to get links of account but problem is:

1. I need to click `Load more` button many time to get full list of accounts to **scrape**
2. There is a popup which comes occasionally so how do I detect it and click cancel button

If possible then I prefer to scrape the full page with request only. Since I have to click buttons so thought of using selenium.

Here is my code:

```
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://society6.com/franciscomffonseca/followers')

time.sleep(3)

try: driver.find_element_by_class_name('bx-button').click() #button to remove popup

except: print("no popups")

driver.find_element_by_class_name('loadMore').click #to click load more button
```

I am using a test page which has 10K followers and want to **scrape** their followers account link. I have already code the **scraper** so just need to see full webpage

[https://society6.com/franciscomffonseca/followers](http://%27https://society6.com/franciscomffonseca/followers%27)

**Scraping** code just in case:

```
r2 = requests.get('https://society6.com/franciscomffonseca/followers')
print(r2.status_code)
r2.raise_for_status

soup2 = BeautifulSoup(r2.content, "html.parser")
a2_tags = soup2.find_all(attrs={"class": "user"})

#attrs={"class": "user-list clearfix"}

follow_accounts = []

for a2 in a2_tags:
    follow_accounts.append('https://society6.com'+a2['href'])

print(follow_accounts)
print("number of accounts scraped: " + str(len(follow_accounts)))
```

Html of `load more` button:

```html
<button class="loadMore" onclick="loadMoreFollowers();">Load More</button>
```

Comment: Did you try to scrape required data with requests to https://society6.com/api/users/franciscomffonseca/followers?page=1&include=html&_=1537173701170 ? Just use `for` loop and increase page number in `page=1` by `1` on each iteration

Comment: No, i don't know much about API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make direct request to Society6 API as below:

```
counter = 1

while True:
    source = requests.get('https://society6.com/api/users/franciscomffonseca/followers?page=%s' % counter).json()
    if source['data']['attributes']['followers']:
        for i in source['data']['attributes']['followers']:
            print(i['card']['link']['href'])
        counter += 1
    else:
        break
```

This will print relative hrefs as

```
/wickedhonna
/wiildrose
/williamconnolly
/whiteca1x
```

If you want absolute hrefs just replace

```
print(i['card']['link']['href'])
```

with

```
print("https://society6.com" + i['card']['link']['href'])
```

Comment: awesome! How did you find the URL and where can i learn more about connecting with website APi's to get more information like this?

Comment: You can open DevTools (F12) -> Switch to Network tab -> Enable "XHR" sub-tab only -> Tap on "Load More" button on page and check URL/headers/response/etc of request that sends

Comment: so if i just replace the url account in the api link then will i get the accounts of that particular account or this api link is unique to only that account?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question... You can do `for i in source['data']['attributes']['followers']: print(i['id'])` to get IDs of followers, then you can pass received ID to URL `https://society6.com/api/users/franciscomffonseca/followers?page=%s` in place of `franciscomffonseca` and you can scrape followers of other users